# Return ggplot2 figure from sourced function

Tags: r, ggplot2

i am struggling with R's print behavior when sourcing a function.
I want to write a function that generates a ggplot and returns that plot in order
to save it later.

So it should look something like this

```
file: func.R

make_plot <- function(data){
p <- ggplot(...)
print(p)
return(p)
}


source('func.R')
p <- make_plot(data)
ggsave('somewhere.png', plot=p)
```

my problem is that the generated plots are empty, and calling print(p)
outside of the function generates a empty plot as well.

If I run the code inside of the function interactively, everything is fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you provide the data you used in make_plot? Also, is the call to ggplot in that function really just ggplot(...)? or is there more to it?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. If I replace your `ggplot` line in the function with `p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point()`, then `p = make_plot(mtcars)` works just fine. Please include enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you working with RStudio? Does the code inside the function still work after you restarted the R session?

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your quick responses. I am very sorry, but the fault was all mine, the real code looked something like

```
  file: func.R
  make_plot <- function(data){
    p <- ggplot(...)
    p + geom_vline ...
    print(p)
    return(p)
  }

  source('func.R')
  p <- make_plot(data)
  ggsave('somewhere.png', plot=p)
```

So the retuned graphic object really was just empty.
It should obviously have been

```
 p <- ggplot(...)
 p <- p + geom_vline ...
```

thank you very much!